# Rails 5 if statement with loop index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `product` model which has a `has_many` relation with my `variation` model. The variations are being looped into the products thumbnail slider and works great.  But, on the products that only have one variation, I don't want to show the thumbnail.

I think I am understanding `with_index` correct and am attempting to use it to show the variation thumbnail, only if thumbnail is greater than 0, but I am not getting the expected results--the other variations thumbs are not showing; just the first one.

```
<% @product.variations.each_with_index do |v, index| %>
  <% if index >= 1 %>
    <% if v.photo_one.present? %>
      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0 7px">
        <div class="btn-filter-wrap">
          <button class="btn-filter"
            data-filter=".id-<%= v.id %>"
            style="background: url(<%= (v.photo_one_url(:thumb)) %>) no-repeat center;
                background-size: contain;
                width: 100%;
                height: 130px">
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" style="width: 100%; text-align:center">
            <h5 style="font-weight: 800;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #555555;
                line-height: 1.8"><%= v.name %></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to show the thumbnail slider when the number of variations are greater than 1 which can be accomplished by looking at `@product.variations.count`. I don't see any need to use the index.

```
<% if @product.variations.count > 1 %>
  <% @product.variations.each do |v| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I agree. Faster than me.

Comment: Since we are using Rails, `if @product.variations.many?` is a bit more concise.

Comment: @mikwat don't need run an extra query, you can loop like this.

  


`<% (@product.variations || []).each do |v| %>
    ...
 <% end %>`

Comment: @TheVinspro That won't work because the requirement is to only iterate over `variations` when there are **more than 1**.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the variations if the product has more than one variation? Try this.

```
<% if @product.variations.count > 1 %>    
      <% @product.variations.each do |variation| %>
            <% if variation.photo_one.present? %>
              <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0 7px">
                <div class="btn-filter-wrap">
                  <button class="btn-filter"
                    data-filter=".id-<%= variantion.id %>"
                    style="background: url(<%= (variation.photo_one_url(:thumb)) %>) no-repeat center;
                        background-size: contain;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 130px">
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2" style="width: 100%; text-align:center">
                    <h5 style="font-weight: 800;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        color: #555555;
                        line-height: 1.8"><%= variation.name %></h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```